# Percetange calculation wrong result

Tags: javascript, math, hour

I want to calculate the percentage of a minute from a given number of hours.
So let's say I have 2 hours. That's 2*60 minutes.
And I want to know how much percent does 1 minute take from 2 hours.
The value should be 0.833, because `0.833 * (2*60) = 100%.`
But how do I get this 0.833 number?

`(hours * 60) / 100` gets me 1.2 when hours=2, not 0.833

It's a simple question I know, but I just cannot figure out why my percentage is not right.

Comment: 0.833 * (2*60) it's not 100% but 99.96, So to get 100% you need to do `0.83333333333333333 * (2*60)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula should be 1 minute / total minutes. So for 2 hrs, its 1 min / 120 min = 0.00833 which is 0.833%.

Answer (score 2):

You made a simple algebra mistake. If you carefully re-write your fraction, you will see that this one is incorrect:

```
(hours * 60) / 100
```

The relation you are looking for is actually:

```
100 / (hours * 60)
```

Indeed, 1 / 1.2 = 0.833

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should look like this :

`percentage = (minutes/totalMinutes)*100`